# Auto Update from Google Sheets to Google Maps Engine?

Tags: google-maps-engine, google-sheets

I have been looking into the Google Maps Engine and I have noticed that you can import data (points) based on a Google Sheets.

This got me thinking, could this be used as a way to auto update a webmap?

From a quick test it seems like the import creates an embedded file, and looses the link to the sheet.

Has anyone looked at the option of using Google Sheets with Maps Engine as a system for adding data to a sheet, and seeing the live update on the map?

Comment: Not Google Sheets, so I'm not putting it as an answer, but instead you may want to look at using Google Fusion table instead of and spread sheet and then you could just use the fusion table data directly in the map (either as a layer in the map, see Google Maps API, or by creating a specific map for that data via the Google Fusion Table interface directly).  You create a new table via Google Drive.  Some more info on fusion tables at https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2571232?hl=en

Comment: Would this require an enterprise version of Google?

Comment: I can do it with my free personal Google Account... you'd have to look into the license restrictions if using it for commercial purposes, I don't know those as well.  But technically, you should be able to.  You would probably have to have beta functionality turned on for Google Drive for your domain to do it as technically it's still a beta product (but it's been out for several years if memory serves correct, so...).  Sorry i don't know the license restrictions.

Comment: To do it though, go to google drive, click create, and one of the listed options should be "Fusion table (experimental)" or something of that sort.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I am trying it now.  Is there an option for polygons and lines, or just points?

Comment: You can read the help documentation for details on how to use the various forms as I've only used one or two, but you can upload a variety of geometries.  You should be able to upload all geometry types as KML geometry, upload text lat & long, or upload address that you geocode within the application.  You should be able to just upload the KML as a geometry object in one column and still have the attributes in separate columns, but again, I've not used all the functionality of it, so you may want to experiment between what it supposedly can and actually can do.

Comment: When I've looked into Fusion Tables, I have not been able to find a way to get them to update live. Meaning that I change data in the source sheet, and the points on my map do not reflect those changes.